# How to make a dataframe download through browser using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heroku, streamlit

I have a function, which generates a dataframe, which I am exporting as an excel sheet, at the end of the function.
`df.to_excel('response.xlsx')`
This excel file is being saved in my working directory.
Now I'm hosting this in Streamlit on heroku as a web app, but I want this excel file to be downloaded in user's local disk (a normal browser download) once this function is called. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: As of today, June 17th 2021, there is no official download implementation. However. there is this workaround:  https://github.com/MarcSkovMadsen/awesome-streamlit/blob/master/gallery/file_download/file_download.py

Comment: Streamlit now supports download natively https://blog.streamlit.io/0-88-0-release-notes/

Answer (score 2):

Snehan Kekre, from streamlit, wrote the following solution in [this thread](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-add-a-download-excel-csv-function-to-a-button/4474/9).

```py
streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import io

import base64
import os
import json
import pickle
import uuid
import re


def download_button(object_to_download, download_filename, button_text, pickle_it=False):
    """
    Generates a link to download the given object_to_download.
    Params:
    ------
    object_to_download:  The object to be downloaded.
    download_filename (str): filename and extension of file. e.g. mydata.csv,
    some_txt_output.txt download_link_text (str): Text to display for download
    link.
    button_text (str): Text to display on download button (e.g. 'click here to download file')
    pickle_it (bool): If True, pickle file.
    Returns:
    -------
    (str): the anchor tag to download object_to_download
    Examples:
    --------
    download_link(your_df, 'YOUR_DF.csv', 'Click to download data!')
    download_link(your_str, 'YOUR_STRING.txt', 'Click to download text!')
    """
    if pickle_it:
        try:
            object_to_download = pickle.dumps(object_to_download)
        except pickle.PicklingError as e:
            st.write(e)
            return None

    else:
        if isinstance(object_to_download, bytes):
            pass

        elif isinstance(object_to_download, pd.DataFrame):
            #object_to_download = object_to_download.to_csv(index=False)
            towrite = io.BytesIO()
            object_to_download = object_to_download.to_excel(towrite, encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=True)
            towrite.seek(0)

        # Try JSON encode for everything else
        else:
            object_to_download = json.dumps(object_to_download)

    try:
        # some strings <-> bytes conversions necessary here
        b64 = base64.b64encode(object_to_download.encode()).decode()

    except AttributeError as e:
        b64 = base64.b64encode(towrite.read()).decode()

    button_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-', '')
    button_id = re.sub('\d+', '', button_uuid)

    custom_css = f""" 
        <style>
            #{button_id} {{
                display: inline-flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                color: rgb(38, 39, 48);
                padding: .25rem .75rem;
                position: relative;
                text-decoration: none;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: rgb(230, 234, 241);
                border-image: initial;
            }} 
            #{button_id}:hover {{
                border-color: rgb(246, 51, 102);
                color: rgb(246, 51, 102);
            }}
            #{button_id}:active {{
                box-shadow: none;
                background-color: rgb(246, 51, 102);
                color: white;
                }}
        </style> """

    dl_link = custom_css + f'<a download="{download_filename}" id="{button_id}" href="data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,{b64}">{button_text}</a><br></br>'

    return dl_link


vals= ['A','B','C']
df= pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=["Title"])  

filename = 'my-dataframe.xlsx'
download_button_str = download_button(df, filename, f'Click here to download {filename}', pickle_it=False)
st.markdown(download_button_str, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

I'd recommend searching the thread on that discussion forum. There seem to be at least 3-4 alternatives to this code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mark Madson has [this workaround](https://github.com/MarcSkovMadsen/awesome-streamlit/blob/master/gallery/file_download/file_download.py) posted on github. I lifted it from the repo and am pasting here as an answer.

```py
import base64
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
  
def st_csv_download_button(df):
    csv = df.to_csv(index=False) #if no filename is given, a string is returned
    b64 = base64.b64encode(csv.encode()).decode()
    href = f'<a href="data:file/csv;base64,{b64}">Download CSV File</a>'
    st.markdown(href, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

usage:

```
st_csv_download_button(my_data_frame)
```

right click + save-as.

I think you can do the same by doing `to_excel` instead of `to_csv`.